# Self- created package stored file

Tags: r

I'm new to R and building R-packages . I had stored a .csv file inside my self-package which I was using in the rscript, but after creating a source package , the format of all the files change.

list.files(system.file(package = 'abc'), recursive = T, full.names = T)
 will not get me access to the file.

Where can I find the .csv file in the self created package? It would be great if I could access it somehow.

Comment: Where exactly in your pacakge file structure did you put the CSV file? Did you put it in a `inst/` folder? Maybe checkout [this guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)

Comment: Oh.. got it .Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place your csv file?
Did you follow the instructions about the inst/extdata folder found [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)?